# How do I prevent visual studio from adding odbc32.lib to 'AdditionalDependencies'?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm refactoring our project files right now, and I'm having an issue that, during linking, several libraries (`kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib`) are being added to `%(Link.AdditionalDependencies)`, and `odbc32.lib` is causing linking errors, since we implement the ODBC Api in another library that's being linked.

I tried to add it to the list of excluded default libraries (`<IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('ODBC'))">odbc32.lib;%(IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries)</IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries>`), but it seems that may not be referring to the same list, since that doesn't do anything.

I *could* avoid this by not using `%(AdditionalDependencies)` in my definition of `AdditionalDependencies`, but it seems like a hack because I would then need to list all the other ones explicitly.

Comment: This comes from a property sheet that is added by default by the project template named "Core Windows Libraries".  View > Other Windows > Property Manager.  You could simply remove it there.  In which case you have to add the ones you need to the linker's setting.  Or sure, just edit the setting directly and remove the libraries you don't want, that's a lot easier.

Comment: Can you just remove it there? Isn't that a global thing, not per-project?

Comment: The property sheet itself is a global thing, don't mess with its content.  The content of the Property Manager window and the linker settings are a per-project/per-configuration setting.

Comment: Do you know how what you're suggesting translates to in the underlying project files? I'm using a text editor right now, don't really want visual studio to mess things up

Comment: Well, using a text editor would be a good way to mess things up.  The IDE was not designed to mess things up.  This just isn't as hard as you make it out to be, edit the linker setting in the IDE, easy peasy.

Comment: What I was alluding to was the fact that visual studio uses msbuild in a specific way, and doesn't always like it if you do your own thing.

Comment: For whatever reason, they seem to have it parse the project files itself for some stuff (like picking up on platforms and configurations) rather than extract the required information using msbuild